# Are we doing DMZ correctly?

Tags: sql-server, ldap, dmz

We are building a client solution that will be hosted on servers in a data-centre. It consists of several servers all related to providing the client solution. There is no internal network to protect but for some reason our UAT environment has the notion of a DMZ in the server diagram.

We have an IIS box which will have a public IP. Then we have two servers DB(Sql Server) and APP that are only on the internal lan with no public IPs. You can only RDP to these servers via VPN. Our IIS server needs sql access so port 1433 is open from IIS box(DMZ) to the sql server. We are also opening several ports from the IIS server to the APP server which hosts WCF services.

My understanding was that a DMZ was meant to protect internal private networks and that these networks should not be accessible from the DMZ but we are now opening up ports to both our APP and DB servers so they are accessible from the DMZ. In the end most of our servers are accessible from the IIS server via certain ports.

We originally wanted to setup our SQL server for AD authentication only but since our IIS server is in the DMZ and has no AD access we will be forced to enable mixed mode authentication in SQL server. This might be another security issue in it's own since we are now forced to store passwords somewhere on the IIS server to be able to auth against sql server.

Are we not perhaps missing the idea of a DMZ?

Answer (score 0):

So with a system where you have a DMZ, there is also a firewall involved.

So your system should look like this I think:

SQL-server hosting internal data
Other servers needed for the company

---- firewall ----

SQL-server hosting data for web solution
AD-server (if needed)
Web-server
FTP-server (could be on the web server also)

With this setup you don't expose company-sensitive database to the outside world and you also don't open up a port in the firewall making it possible for attackers to (maybe) get access to the internal database which has company sensitive data...

Just my suggestion based on the information provided.